# Can't open Firefox-based Browser

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried to open modified FireFox browser using Selenium WebDriver.
(This Firefox-based browser as same as original Firefox, just with additional functionality.)

This Browser **opens** and then I got Error:

> **["OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException" in WebDriver.dll]**
>   TypeError: Given browserName [object String] "firefox", but my name is [object String] "anotherbrowser"

My code[C#]:

```
var path = new FirefoxBinary(@"C:\FireFox_BasedBrowser\anotherbrowser.exe");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(path, null); //here's error
```

After searching I found this advice on Java:

```
String bname = "Browser name";
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("Path to browser binary");
options.setCapability("browserName", bname);
options.setCapability("marionette", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I tried to rewrite it into C#:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
cap.SetCapability("browserName", "anotherbrowser");
cap.SetCapability("firefox_binary", @"C:\FireFox_BasedBrowser\anotherbrowser.exe");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap); //here's error
```

But I also got an error:

> **["System.ArgumentException" in WebDriver.dll]** There is already an option for the browserName capability. Please use
>   the  instead.

Please, help me, I can't find any solutions.

---

P.s. I can't use original Firefox browser, because it doesn't have same advantages as this modified Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I Can't re-write Java's solution to C# in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47318176/i-cant-re-write-javas-solution-to-c-sharp-in-selenium)

Comment: Who's interested, I found a solution:                                                                              

    `FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.UseLegacyImplementation = true;
    options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"Path to Browser";
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser", "anotherbrowser");
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(...)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriverService_CreateDefaultService_2.htm) to define another path for Firefox:

```c#
var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\drivers", "geckodriver.exe");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

Comment: Browser opens, but then I get error: **["OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException" in WebDriver.dll] Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:10522/**

Comment: @ILya, my bad, the example was wrong. Note that the latest version of `geckodriver.exe` requires Firefox 55 or superior.

Comment: I'd tried, but I got same error: **["OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException" in WebDriver.dll] TypeError: Given browserName [object String] "firefox", but my name is [object String] "anotherbrowser"**. I think, that the problem with ''anotherbrowser'' name, it isn't "firefox"

Comment: @ILya, your exception doesn't make sense with this example. Looks like you changed something else. You can change the binary for Firefox, but the name defined in the capabilities must remain `firefox`.

Comment: It's all code, which I have in my project. And I used Grecko 16.0, My ''AnotherBrowser'' based on Firefox 54.0. I think, it will be a little bit hard to change names in .exe. Whats about advice on Java, which I get earlier?