# I Can't re-write Java's solution to C# in Selenium

Tags: java, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have some problems with modified FireFox browser on C#. 
When the Browser opens and I get an error:

> TypeError: Given browserName [object String] "firefox", but my name is [object String] "anotherbrowser"

I think, it's because of browser's name "anotherbrowser" instead of "firefox" in it's binary code.

So I found the solution on Java:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("Path to browser binary");
options.setCapability("browserName", "anotherbrowser");
options.setCapability("marionette", false);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I tested it, and its work fine. But I need on C#, so I tried to rewrite it:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
cap.SetCapability("browserName", "anotherbrowser");
cap.SetCapability("firefox_binary", @"Path to browser binary");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap); //here's error
```

But I got an error:

> There is already an option for the browserName capability. Please use
>   the  instead.

Please, help me to re-write Java solution to C#. I got troubles, because there isn't same method in C#, like in Java: *"options.setCapability(" "," ");"*

---

P.s. I can't use original Firefox browser, because it doesn't have same advantages as my modified Firefox.

Comment: `cap.BrowserName="whatever";`

Comment: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_DesiredCapabilities.htm

Comment: @Gusman the BrowserName property on capabilities only has a getter.
`public string BrowserName { get; }`

Comment: @MichielBugher Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who's interested, I found a solution:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.UseLegacyImplementation = true;
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"Path to Browser";
options.AddAdditionalCapability("browser", "anotherbrowser");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the options class like you are in Java?

In c# you can use something like this:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Path\to\firefox";

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options)
```

According to: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

> The name of the browser being used; should be one of {android, chrome, firefox, htmlunit, internet explorer, iPhone, iPad, opera, safari}

Based on what the documentation says, I would assume that you do not need to set the "browserName" capability to use your custom binaries.

Comment: I tried now and I got an error: **_TypeError: Given browserName [object String] "firefox", but my name is [object String] "anotherbrowser"_**. I think, `options.SetPreference("browserName", "anotherbrowser");` is written wrong or it just doesn't work.

Comment: @ILya Try setting the following for the binary: `options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Path\to\firefox";`

Comment: @ILya Also, according to this: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities The browserName is a valid option for DesiredCapabilities. It only supports certain names though.

Comment: What is your goal in changing the name of the browser? If you pass it your custom binaries properly, it should use those instead of the default installed one.

Comment: I'm not a developer of this browser. Maybe I can change browserName in binary by WinHex, but, its wrong way I think, because a lot of bugs will be.

Comment: Why does browserName matter if you're using your modified binaries?